# A list(of String) I have fails to populate on a post back but populates just fine on the initial page load

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am relatively new to programming so please bare with me if I use improper terminology for the question I am about to ask.

Currently, I have a list(of String) that I am populating with 2 values that I am pulling from a database. Code Below.

```
objCn.Open()
    sqlTermSelect.Connection = objCn
    sqlTermSelect.CommandText = "Select PartsTerm, LaborTerm FROM SKU INNER JOIN Agreement On SKU.SKU = Agreement.SKU WHERE Agreement = @Agreement"
    sqlTermSelect.Parameters.Add("@Agreement", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = txtAgreement.Text

    Dim termDA As New SqlDataAdapter(sqlTermSelect)
    Dim termDT As New DataTable()
    termDA.Fill(termDT)
    For i As Integer = 0 To termDT.Rows.Count - 1
        listValues.Add(termDT.Rows(i)("PartsTerm").ToString())
        listValues.Add(termDT.Rows(i)("LaborTerm").ToString())
    Next
    objCn.Close()
```

I am then storing the values of this list in two variables that I use as checks to see whether certain controls on my page should be enabled/visible or disabled/invisible.

The page that this is affecting operates(for lack of a better word) in two ways, the first is a brand new page with empty controls that the user fills out. The second way is if the user begins to fill out the page and leaves, the data they filled out is saved and they can return later to continue filling it out (I am not 100% certain but I believe when a user returns to an "in progress" page it is a post back, I could be wrong, I'm not terribly sure how this is handled).

The problem I am having comes to when this list is populated with the database values.  When I go to a brand new page, the list is populated and the controls mentioned above are enabled/disabled appropriately with no issues, the issue arises when I go to an "in progress" page the list values don't populate and the controls that should be disabled are enabled.  Essentially, I am looking for a way to populate this list every time a page is opened, "in progress" or brand new.  The code above that populates the list is in the PageLoad() event and I have verified that it is not in a "If Not IsPostBack" statement.

Any and all help would be greatly appreciated, if there is anything I should add to this post code related I would be more than happy to supply it.

Comment: Could you move your list populating method out of PageLoad, to its own function, and call it from each event you need it?

Comment: Hey @Andrew Mortimer, I figured it out, and when I boil it down it comes out to pretty much what you said.  I copied the code populating the list and used it in each event needed, which fixed the problem. I am going to create a function to do it now to reduce code clutter.  If you post this as an answer I would love to flag it as the answer.  Thank you for the response, I really appreciate it.

Comment: where is how are you defining and saving the listvalues variable? That's going to be important here. The values of such variables ONLY exist during the page load and render and then after the page is sent to the browser - then all such variables are gone and done exist anymore. So, VERY important -- where and how is listvalues defined? So this so called concept of scope is important.

Comment: Hey @Albert D. Kallal, sorry for the late response.  Thanks for you time and comment, currently I am setting the values of the list in the page load event, however the problem was occuring because I was declaring them in the wrong place so when I would re-navigate(for lack of a better word) to the page the values wouldn't persist. I have since figured out a solution to the problem and am spending the next little bit cleaning up the code similarly to how Andrew(above) mentioned.